# End ticks missing on colorbars in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, colorbar

I want to make contour plots with colorbars that are symmetric about zero and have ticks at the maximum and minimum values. I am having a problem where the end ticks on my colorbars are not showing.

Here is an example:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
A = np.random.random((10,10))*10-5
x = np.arange(0, A.shape[1])
y = np.arange(0, A.shape[0])

minval=-5
maxval=5

im1 = ax.contourf(x,y,A,150, vmin=minval, vmax=maxval,cmap="BrBG",extend='both')  
    

cbar = ax.figure.colorbar(
    im1, 
    ax=ax,
    ticks=[minval, minval/2, 0, maxval/2, maxval],
    orientation="vertical", 
    )
```

Which results in this figure (it will not let me embed the image, see link), that has tick marks at 0 and +/-2.5 but not +/-5:
contour plot with a colorbar that has ticks at -2.5, 0 and 2.5 but not at -5 or 5
[image: 1]

I tried these following add-ons with no avail:

```
im1.set_clim(minval, maxval)
cbar.ax.set_xticklabels([minval, minval/2, '0', maxval/2, maxval])
plt.show()
```

I'm nearly positive that this used to work fine but has recently been skipping out on the end tick marks. I'm running it in a jupyter notebook. Ideas?

Comment: `ax.set_xticks(np.arange(10))` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you call `contourf(..., levels=150, ...)`, matplotlib will create 151 equally spaced boundaries between the minimum and maximum of the data. The way `np.random.random` works, the minimum of `A` is slightly larger than `-5` and the maximum slightly smaller than `5`. So, these extreme values don't belong to the level boundaries. And won't be visible in the colorbar. To have them visible, the level boundaries could be set explicitly to include these values:

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
A = np.random.random((10, 10)) * 10 - 5
x = np.arange(0, A.shape[1])
y = np.arange(0, A.shape[0])

minval = -5
maxval = 5

im1 = ax.contourf(x, y, A, levels=np.linspace(minval, maxval, 151), cmap="BrBG", extend='both')

cbar = fig.colorbar(
    im1,
    ax=ax,
    ticks=[minval, minval/2, 0, maxval/2, maxval],
    orientation="vertical"
)
cbar.ax.set_yticklabels([minval, minval/2, "0", maxval/2, maxval])
plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]

Also note that for a vertical colorbar, the `y`-direction is used (`cbar.ax.set_yticklabels`).

Comment: That works. 

I don't understand why setting minval and maxval doesn't work though! In my actual code I am not using random numbers. But I will just use this as a solution.

Comment: Maybe something changed internally in the implementation of `contourf`?

Comment: @andrewp109 on twitter had what sounds like the reason why! "It's because you used an integer for the levels. That creates n levels evenly spaced between the max and min, so it won't create levels outside that range. To fix, make a vector (levels=np.linspace(-5, 5, 150)) and replace the 150 with that."

Comment: Well, it should be `np.linspace(..., 151)` to get 150 levels (151 boundaries)

Answer (score 1):

Do you specifically need to be using `contourf`? If you use `pcolormesh` instead, almost your exact code will give you the ticks where you want (you just have to move "extend" to the cbar call vs the pcolormesh call). That doesn't answer your question, but dodges the issue...

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
A = np.random.random((10,10))*10-5
x = np.arange(0, A.shape[1])
y = np.arange(0, A.shape[0])

minval=-5
maxval=5

# im1 = ax.contourf(x,y,A,150, vmin=minval-10, vmax=maxval+10,cmap=plt.cm.get_cmap("BrBG",32),extend='both')  
im1 = ax.pcolormesh(x,y,A,vmin=minval,vmax=maxval,cmap=plt.cm.get_cmap('BrBG'))


cbar = fig.colorbar(
    im1, 
    ax=ax,
    ticks=[minval, minval/2, 0, maxval/2, maxval],
    orientation="vertical", extend='both'
    )
```

Comment: pcolormesh gives me a blocky look, I want the colors to be smooth. But it does plot the colorbars correctly!